# What is the best way to Drag & Drop with js like the map in Google maps?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I am searching a light and powerful way to Drag & Drop contents like the map in Google Maps.

I already managed it, but I am not sure if it is the best way. I trapped the mouse (and touch) events, like mouse up, mouse down and mouse move, and changed every time the x and y position of every div-element (position:absolute). It works, but in most browsers on bigger screens, it isn't fluent.

So is there a way to do it more performant?

Second question: When I drag the contents and the mouse leave the browser window, it stopps dragging. Is there a solution to prevent this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Also, if you're not using a framework, I would suggest jQuery UI. http://jqueryui.com/home

Comment: I am currently using Prototype. The code is too big to post, but here is the file where it is implemented: http://new.paperchat.lu/js/paperchat.js (Line 2507: Input) Call http://new.paperchat.lu/ to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic approach is correct: you need to use mouse* event handlers to get the functionality you want.  I have two ideas on how you might help the performance:

- Use the browser-specific events.  IE (and possibly others) has a few of  its own mouse events, in addition to the standard ones; using these might improve your IE-only performance (but I don't know for sure, so you'd have to experiment)
- Delegate events.  If you have fifty elements that you are attaching event handlers to, it's going to eat up a lot of memory and affect performance.  What you can do instead is attach those event handlers to a common parent element (eg. your "canvas" DIV) and then use the event details that get passed in to the handler to determine which element actually triggered the event.  If you want to read up more on this, the basic principle is called event bubbling.

Those are just a couple of thoughts (the best I can do without more specifics); hope they help.

Comment: P.S. To answer your second question, I don't believe there is anything you can do; a web page's ability to be affected by the user's actions is limited to the browser, and as soon as the operating system decides not to send info to the browser, you're out of luck.  I believe the best you can do is assume the mouse is going to continue at its current vector when it leaves the browser, and keep acting on that vector until the mouse returns to the browser ... but doing something like that would be far from trivial.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will search a bit about event bubbling. About the second question: @JarredFarrish suggested using jQuery. I visited the site and noticed: When I drag this box out of the browser window, it still works. (http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) The mouse positions couldn't be assumed..

Comment: Huh, there must be some trick I don't know about; sorry for the wrong answer on that one.  Of course, you don't need to use jQuery (you *could* just go look at how they do it), but both jQuery and jQuery UI are awesome (with UI being only slightly less awesome than jQuery core), so personally I'd recommend just using it if it works for your app.

Comment: P.S. If you do want to look at how jQuery UI does it, look at the _mouseUp, _mouseMove, and _mouseDown definitions in the jQuery UI code; together they simulate the _mouseDrag event that Draggable (and other jQuery UI stuff) uses. _mouseMove is the main one to look at, but you need to look at the other ones too because they all use a common _mouseStarted property.

Answer (score 0):

look at this library .
 http://openlayers.org/ . 
 you can show some layers of data .